# RegionMeasure not measuring my region

Tags: regions, geometry

This tetrahedron and sphere intersect:

```
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {0.8, 0, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]/2, 1}, {1, -1, 3/4}, 
           cent = {0.7, -0.0335, 0.43}};
regTet = MeshRegion[pts, Tetrahedron[{1, 2, 3, 5}]];
regSphere = Region[Sphere[cent, .1]];
Show[regTet, regSphere]
```

[image]

Using RegionIntersection to pick out the intersection seems to work:

```
int = RegionIntersection[regTet, regSphere]
```

[image]

and everything checks out with RegionQ:

```
{RegionQ[regSphere], RegionQ[regTet], RegionQ[int]}
{True, True, True}
```

Now I can get the measure of the tetrahedron and of the sphere

```
{RegionMeasure[regSphere], RegionMeasure[regTet]}
{0.125664, 0.054984}
```

but when trying to get the measure of the intersection:

```
RegionMeasure[int]
RegionMeasure::reg: int is not a correctly specified region.
```

It feels like I must be making a simple mistake... but how do I get the area of the intersection of the surface of the sphere and the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work with graphics primitives instead, things work:

```
tet = Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {0.8, 0, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]/2, 1}, {0.7, -0.0335, 0.43}}];
sph = Sphere[{0.7, -0.0335, 0.43}, .1];

Show @ Graphics3D[{tet, sph}]
RegionMeasure @ RegionIntersection[tet, sph]
```

[image]

> 0.0207873

Comment: Thanks -- this is a nice work-around. The Region commands seem so tempting... I wish I understood them better.